# VS 2010 not defining symbols for compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

To begin with, I am not new to Visual Studio, but am new to 2010 (specifically 2010 Premium).  I am migrating several C++ projects from earlier versions of VS.  The problem is that I am defining a symbol in the Preprocessor Definitions of the Project Settings, but it is not being defined in the compile.  It appears on the Command Line of the Project Settings, but does not appear on the compile line in the build log.  Essentially the situation looks like:

Preprocessor Definitions:  MY_SYMBOL

Command Line:    .../D "MY_SYMBOL"...

But the build log does not include it.

The code that uses it sometimes is greyed out, sometimes not.  There are other symbols defined, but those were migrated from the project files from the earlier VS versions, and they appear correctly on the compile line in the build log.  Nothing I have added to the Preprocessor Definitions actually makes it to the compile.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know specifics, but I think it has to be without quotes and with no space.  `/DMY_SYMBOL`

Comment: @MooingDuck: The space and the quotes are fine - MSVC and GCC (at least MinGW) deal with them just fine.

Comment: The Visual Studio project conversion tools often have buggy behavior - you might want to try to recreate the project by hand if possible.

Comment: I wondered about the quotes and space, but it was VS that was putting those in, not me.  I ended up reconverting the whole VS6 workspace and projects, and all of a sudden my symbols were getting defined.  So it may have been a problem with the conversion tool that didn't happen the second time around.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I have a /D define value in my log, but #pragma shows it's never defined either. I am manually adding property sheets as opposed to converting files.